# What is causing this read signalR error in my KendoUI Grid?

Tags: c#, kendo-ui, signalr

I am getting very intermittent behaviour in my KendoUI Grid which has a SignalR data source.  Originally it looked like the grid wasn't loading, however, after adding an error handler to the dataSource, I gained a little more insight into what is going on.

> "Failed to invoke 'read' due to an error on the server.
> InvalidDataException: Invocation provides 0 argument(s) but target
> expects 1."

At first glance, you'd think that makes sense, there must be a parameter in the Read action of the HUB that isn't being satisfied?  No, there is no expectation of parameter in the hub and yet this error persists.

Here are two notes that need to be considered in my setup.

- I'm using the Azure SignalR Service
- My grid is hidden in a bootstrap 5 tab, and only binds when that tab is activated.

To start, I'll walk through my code and setup first.

***Startup.cs***

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddSignalR(options => { 
        options.EnableDetailedErrors = true; 
    }).AddAzureSignalR().AddJsonProtocol(options => {
        options.PayloadSerializerOptions.PropertyNamingPolicy = null;
    });
    ...
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
    app.UseAzureSignalR(endpoints =>
    {
        endpoints.MapHub<TodoHub>("/todoHub");
    });
    ...
}
```

***TodoHub.cs***

```
namespace MyCompany.UI.Hubs
{
    public class TodoHub : Hub
    {
        private readonly IRepository<ToDo> _userTodo;

        public TodoHub(IRepository<ToDo> userTodo)
        {
            _userTodo = userTodo;
        }
        public override Task OnConnectedAsync()
        {
            Groups.AddToGroupAsync(Context.ConnectionId, GetGroupName());
            return base.OnConnectedAsync();
        }
        public override Task OnDisconnectedAsync(Exception e)
        {
            Groups.RemoveFromGroupAsync(Context.ConnectionId, GetGroupName());
            return base.OnDisconnectedAsync(e);
        }
        public IQueryable<ToDo> Read()
        {
            IQueryable<ToDo> data = _userTodo.GetAll();
            return data;
        }
        public string GetGroupName()
        {
            return GetRemoteIpAddress();
        }
        public string GetRemoteIpAddress()
        {
            return Context.GetHttpContext()?.Connection.RemoteIpAddress.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

***site.js***

```
var todo_url = "/todoHub";
var todo_hub = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder().withUrl(todo_url, {
    transport: signalR.HttpTransportType.LongPolling
}).build();
var todo_hub_start = todo_hub.start({
    json: true
});
```

***grid.js***

```
function load_grid_todo() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        $('#grid_todo').kendoGrid({
            dataSource: {
                error: function (e) {
                    var xhr = e.xhr;
                    var statusCode = e.status;
                    var errorThrown = e.errorThrown;
                    console.log(e)                    
                },
                filter: {
                    logic: "and",
                    filters: [
                        {
                            field: "Created_User",
                            operator: "eq",
                            value: $('#global_user_identifier').val()
                        },
                        {
                            field: "Completed",
                            operator: "eq",
                            value: 0
                        }
                    ]
                },
                type: "signalr",
                autoSync: true,
                transport: {
                    signalr: {
                        promise: todo_hub_start,
                        hub: todo_hub,
                        server: {
                            read: "read",
                            update: "update",
                            create: "create",
                            destroy: "destroy"
                        },
                        client: {
                            read: "read",
                            update: "update",
                            create: "create",
                            destroy: "destroy"
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    schema: {
                        model: {
                            id: "Id"                            
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            autoBind: true,
            scrollable: true,
            sortable: true,
            pageable: false,
            columns: [
                {
                    field: "Id"                    
                }              
            ]
        });
        resolve();
    });
}
```

***Tab triggers***

This listens to the tab event `shown` and calls the grid function if an instance of the grid doesn't exist.  It does this asynchronously.

```
window.addEventListener("load", function () {
    document.querySelector("#main-tabs")
        .addEventListener("shown.bs.tab", async (e) => {
            if (e.target.id == "overview-tab") {
                let instance_grid_todo = $("#grid_todo").getKendoGrid();
                if (!instance_grid_todo) {
                    await load_grid_todo();
                }
            }
        });
}, false);
```

As you can see, it's a straight up read request with no parameters, the defined kendo filters that are shown only count towards the returned data set, this was done intentionally as to keep the read request free from any filtering.

So the question it, what can/is causing this message and is my setup incorrect?